# Excluding email lists while selecting specific values at once

Tags: mysql, select, exists

I am trying to do 2 things here within 1 SELECT query (I know I could do this in 2 steps but I want to avoid intermediary tables):

1. Select specific values (M and W only — there are other values possible but I just want these 2 and not other) from a TABLE 'anothertable'.
2. While avoiding selecting opt-outs and bounced emails (11k rows, <5 columns).

I am not sure if the syntax is correct since the query is loading for ever. Size should not be an issue though (27k rows, <5 columns and 2 core processors).

```
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE `mytable` AS (

SELECT * FROM `anothertable` A

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Email FROM `optout` B WHERE B.Email = A.Email)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Email FROM `allbounced` C WHERE C.emailbounced = A.Email)

GROUP BY Email
HAVING 
(SUM(CASE WHEN target = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR   -- MAN  is present
SUM(CASE WHEN target = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND   -- WOMAN  is present
SUM(CASE WHEN target NOT IN ('M', 'W') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0)  -- only MAN or WOMAN

);

END
```

Comment: Impossible without knowing a lot more about what you're trying to do, and what your database looks like (both in terms of schema and contents).

Comment: You should probably show a little bit of the schema.  The processing of `target` is curious.  It seems to come from the `vbq-sales-customers` table.  What are the plausible values?  Clearly `M` and `W` are allowed; are any others?  Presumably, the intent is to eliminate email addresses which are associated with multiple customers where the address is associated with people of both the `M` and `W` genders.  That would require two or more people who are identified by gender to be sharing an email address (e.g. `support@example.com` used by `Sarah` (`W`) and `Albert` (`M`)).

Comment: What are the cardinalities of the tables — how many customers; how many opt-outs; how many bounces?  What indexes are in place on the tables?  What is the query plan?  How many email addresses are actually shared by multiple people?  Would `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT target) = 1` work any better?  Can you filter on `WHERE target IN ('M', 'W')` instead of the third SUM term?

Comment: Please add the extra information to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: You are doing two subqueries, which are very expensive. Is there a reason why you are not suing JOINs? Also, it is always good to (1) **provide a schema** and (2) **run EXPLAIN EXTENDED**, to know what optimisation strategy is MySQL using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When possible you should use `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS`. This should be faster:

```
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE `mytable` AS (

SELECT Email FROM `anothertable` A
WHERE Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM `optout`)
AND Email NOT IN (SELECT emailbounced FROM `allbounced`)

GROUP BY Email
HAVING 
(SUM(CASE WHEN target = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR   -- MAN  is present
SUM(CASE WHEN target = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND   -- WOMAN  is present
SUM(CASE WHEN target NOT IN ('M', 'W') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0)  -- only MAN or WOMAN

);

END
```